# Is it possible for a non-citizen nor GC holder do crowdfunding inside the US?

Tags: united-states, corporate-law, finance, immigration

Supose that a person A is an international student in the US. A has an idea and like to launch a company on that. I know A doesn't have a work permission but also believe that A can register a company and invest in it.

So can A legally register a new company, do crowdfunding to raise funds for it, then hire people to work for the company?

Comment: I've voted to close as "questions that clearly ask for specific legal advice are off-topic" but I will reconsider if/when it is suitably edited to make the question more generic and less specific.

Comment: @RockApe There's no need to nitpick here. Yes the question uses "I" rather than "Bob" but it is generic, not fact-specific.

Comment: Worth considering, although not exactly a duplicate. https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/66851/how-can-a-f-2-visa-holder-establish-a-company-but-cant-work-inside-the-us?rq=1 and https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/67499/is-it-possible-to-create-a-non-profit-business-on-f-2-visa-status?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Yes and No.

Crowdfunding is basically just inviting people to invest. No work permission is needed for it, so the answer to this is Yes.

However, managing the funds and hiring people to work *is* work. You would need to appoint a director with work permission to do it. So, the answer to this is No.